# Bitbucket, Api 2.0, PR attachment

Tags: curl, bitbucket

I would like to upload an attachment into a PR on bitbucket API 2.0.

In comment case it works easily:

```
curl \
--user usename:pass  \
--request POST   \
--url https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}/comments   \
--header 'Accept: application/json'   \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'   \
--data '{"content": { "raw": "test" }}'
```

but unfortunately I don't know how can it works when I would like to upload an attachment into a PR or a branch.

Similar solution: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-enclose-file-to-pull-request-comment-via-rest-api-952073003.html

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also trying to upload an attachment as part of PR comment using the Bitbucket API 2.0

Comment: Nope, I used the report functions for that purpose (annotations): https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-reports/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-commit-commit-reports-reportid-annotations-get

Answer (score 0):

To quote https://bitbucket.org/blog/pr-attachments publish on September 24, 2020:

> Post attachments from build tools
>
> A public API for pull request attachments is on the way. Right now,
> internal teams at Atlassian are using this feature to post visual
> diffs from their build tools. The same could be done with logs in text
> files. The possibilities are endless.

The feature has not been added as of September 2023.